# How to turn a directed unweighted graph into a tree, rooted at a given vertex?

Tags: data-structures, graph

If I have a directed unweighted graph and want to create a tree from a specific vertex in the graph thus, giving all paths from said vertex. How would this be done?

Comment: What you are asking is purely a matter of representation: your input is a representation of a graph, and your output should be a different representation of the same graph. But your question fails to mention what type of representation you are starting with. Do you have an adjacency matrix of the graph? An adjacency list? Please provide an example of a small graph and the corresponding input and output that you would want.

Comment: Also, is the graph acyclic to start with?

Comment: Also, have you heard about "breadth-first search" for instance, and do you have some idea of how it could be related to your question?